Function call with Azure OpenAI gpt-4o returns 400 error although the messages are valid
The original post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1684271/function-call-with-azure-openai-gpt-4o-returns-400
I am testing the new Azure Open AI gpt-4o model but I get the error with function call even though my input messages are correct.
Here are the code
from openai import OpenAI, AzureOpenAI
# client = OpenAI()
client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint='https://xxx.openai.azure.com/',    
    api_version="2024-02-01",
    api_key='xxx'
)

msg=[
    {
        "role": "user", 
        "content": [
            {"type": "text", "text": "What is in the image?"}, 
            {
                "type": "image_url", 
                "image_url": {
                    "url": "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/c04/puppy-1367856.jpg"
                }
            }
        ]
     }, 
     {"role": "assistant", "content": "There is a small dog in the image"}, 
     {"role": "user", "content": [{"type": "text", "text": "What is today?"}]}, 
     {"role": "assistant", "content": "", "tool_calls": [{"id": "call_rkBDeJsY9mCnzFchblUV2ZHt", "function": {"arguments": "{}", "name": "get_current_date"}, "type": "function"}]}, 
     {"tool_call_id": "call_rkBDeJsY9mCnzFchblUV2ZHt", "role": "tool", "name": "get_current_date", "content": "2024-05-21 19:52:24.775703"}
]

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model='gpt-4o',
    messages=msg,           
    temperature=0
)
choice = completion.choices[0].message
print(choice)

And the error
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "An assistant message with 'tool_calls' must be followed by tool messages responding to each 'tool_call_id'. The following tool_call_ids did not have response messages: call_rkBDeJsY9mCnzFchblUV2ZHt", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'messages', 'code': None}}

Notes:
The error only occurs when I include the image https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/c04/puppy-1367856.jpg in the first question
When I use OpenAI service instead of AzureOpenAI, the code is running perfectly. I believe that is the issue with AzureOpenAI client. I want to ask if you have ever been facing this?
Many thanks.
When I use OpenAI service instead of AzureOpenAI, the code is running perfectly.
I also tried remove the image from the first message, it also works.

This is now fixed. Please check. During the early release it was giving issue.

Yes the issue has been fixed, thanks

I'm having the same issue right now. Is it a version problem?
